# Why is wxCrafter Hello World program not working? [C++, wxWidgets]

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I followed the wxCrafter Hello World tutorial: https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/WxCrafterHelloWorld

Building process shows no errors, however no dialog shows up when I click "Build->Run" in CodeLite 13, for some reason nothing happens :/

main.cpp:

```
#include <wx/app.h>
#include <wx/event.h>
#include "MainDialog.h"
#include <wx/image.h>


// Define the MainApp
class MainApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    MainApp() {}
    virtual ~MainApp() {}

    virtual bool OnInit() {
        // Add the common image handlers
        wxImage::AddHandler( new wxPNGHandler );
        wxImage::AddHandler( new wxJPEGHandler );

        MainDialog mainDialog(NULL);
        mainDialog.ShowModal();
        return false;
    }
};

DECLARE_APP(MainApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(MainApp)
```

MainDialog.h:

```
#ifndef MAINDIALOG_H
#define MAINDIALOG_H
#include "wxcrafter.h"

class MainDialog : public MainDialogBaseClass
{
public:
    MainDialog(wxWindow* parent);
    virtual ~MainDialog();
protected:
    virtual void OnButtonokButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& event);
};
#endif // MAINDIALOG_H
```

MainDialog.cpp:

```
#include "MainDialog.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h> 

MainDialog::MainDialog(wxWindow* parent)
    : MainDialogBaseClass(parent)
{
}

MainDialog::~MainDialog()
{
}

void MainDialog::OnButtonokButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    ::wxMessageBox(_("Hello World"));
}
```

wxcrafter.h:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This file was auto-generated by codelite's wxCrafter Plugin
// wxCrafter project file: wxcrafter.wxcp
// Do not modify this file by hand!
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef _WORKSPACE_MEDCEN_PLUS_WXCRAFTER_BASE_CLASSES_H
#define _WORKSPACE_MEDCEN_PLUS_WXCRAFTER_BASE_CLASSES_H

#include <wx/artprov.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/dialog.h>
#include <wx/iconbndl.h>
#include <wx/settings.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/statline.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/xrc/xh_bmp.h>
#include <wx/xrc/xmlres.h>
#if wxVERSION_NUMBER >= 2900
#include <wx/persist.h>
#include <wx/persist/bookctrl.h>
#include <wx/persist/toplevel.h>
#include <wx/persist/treebook.h>
#endif

#ifdef WXC_FROM_DIP
#undef WXC_FROM_DIP
#endif
#if wxVERSION_NUMBER >= 3100
#define WXC_FROM_DIP(x) wxWindow::FromDIP(x, NULL)
#else
#define WXC_FROM_DIP(x) x
#endif

class MainDialogBaseClass : public wxDialog
{
protected:
    wxStaticText* m_staticText21;
    wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl23;
    wxStaticLine* m_staticLine15;
    wxButton* m_buttonOK;
    wxButton* m_buttonCancel;

protected:
    virtual void OnButtonokButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& event)
    {
        event.Skip();
    }

public:
    wxStaticText* GetStaticText21()
    {
        return m_staticText21;
    }
    wxTextCtrl* GetTextCtrl23()
    {
        return m_textCtrl23;
    }
    wxStaticLine* GetStaticLine15()
    {
        return m_staticLine15;
    }
    wxButton* GetButtonOK()
    {
        return m_buttonOK;
    }
    wxButton* GetButtonCancel()
    {
        return m_buttonCancel;
    }
    MainDialogBaseClass(wxWindow* parent,
        wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
        const wxString& title = _("My Dialog"),
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxSize(500, 300),
        long style = wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER);
    virtual ~MainDialogBaseClass();
};

#endif
```

wxcrafter.cpp:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This file was auto-generated by codelite's wxCrafter Plugin
// wxCrafter project file: wxcrafter.wxcp
// Do not modify this file by hand!
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "wxcrafter.h"

// Declare the bitmap loading function
extern void wxC9ED9InitBitmapResources();

static bool bBitmapLoaded = false;

MainDialogBaseClass::MainDialogBaseClass(wxWindow* parent,
    wxWindowID id,
    const wxString& title,
    const wxPoint& pos,
    const wxSize& size,
    long style)
    : wxDialog(parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
{
    if(!bBitmapLoaded) {
        // We need to initialise the default bitmap handler
        wxXmlResource::Get()->AddHandler(new wxBitmapXmlHandler);
        wxC9ED9InitBitmapResources();
        bBitmapLoaded = true;
    }
    this->SetFocus();

    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    this->SetSizer(mainSizer);

    wxBoxSizer* boxSizer19 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    mainSizer->Add(boxSizer19, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    m_staticText21 = new wxStaticText(
        this, wxID_ANY, _("Static Text Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(-1, -1)), 0);

    boxSizer19->Add(m_staticText21, 0, wxALL, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    m_textCtrl23 = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT(""), wxDefaultPosition, wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(-1, -1)), 0);
#if wxVERSION_NUMBER >= 3000
    m_textCtrl23->SetHint(wxT(""));
#endif

    boxSizer19->Add(m_textCtrl23, 0, wxALL, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    mainSizer->Add(0, 0, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    m_staticLine15 =
        new wxStaticLine(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(-1, -1)), wxLI_HORIZONTAL);

    mainSizer->Add(m_staticLine15, 0, wxALL | wxEXPAND, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    wxBoxSizer* boxSizer12 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    mainSizer->Add(boxSizer12, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALL, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    m_buttonOK = new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, _("OK"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(-1, -1)), 0);
    m_buttonOK->SetDefault();

    boxSizer12->Add(m_buttonOK, 0, wxALL, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    m_buttonCancel =
        new wxButton(this, wxID_CANCEL, _("Cancel"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(-1, -1)), 0);

    boxSizer12->Add(m_buttonCancel, 0, wxALL, WXC_FROM_DIP(5));

    SetName(wxT("MainDialogBaseClass"));
    SetSize(wxDLG_UNIT(this, wxSize(500, 300)));
    if(GetSizer()) {
        GetSizer()->Fit(this);
    }
    if(GetParent()) {
        CentreOnParent(wxBOTH);
    } else {
        CentreOnScreen(wxBOTH);
    }
#if wxVERSION_NUMBER >= 2900
    if(!wxPersistenceManager::Get().Find(this)) {
        wxPersistenceManager::Get().RegisterAndRestore(this);
    } else {
        wxPersistenceManager::Get().Restore(this);
    }
#endif
    // Connect events
    m_buttonOK->Connect(
        wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(MainDialogBaseClass::OnButtonokButtonClicked), NULL, this);
}

MainDialogBaseClass::~MainDialogBaseClass()
{
    m_buttonOK->Disconnect(
        wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(MainDialogBaseClass::OnButtonokButtonClicked), NULL, this);
}
```

Comment: because you didn't bind the event to the handler. Please check the event handling portion of wxWidgets documentation.

Comment: Also curious - which version of wxCrafter/CodeLite do you use?

Comment: Version 13, from Debian Buster CodeLite repository

Comment: I read wxWidgets handling event wiki entry, however I can't figure this out

Comment: I didn't mean Wiki. I meant an official wxWidgets documentation. But for now I will give you the answer. Also, you should check the official wxWidgets samples, starting with the minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with either the C::L installation or the wxCrafter plugin.

If you did follow the referenced tutorial, it should create a wxButton object as a member of the dialog and bind the event handler to it.

Can you compile and run the `minimal` sample from the wxWidgets install?

Comment: At least on Code Lite 13, the button is already there when you choose to start a new project with a wxCrafter Dialog, I just added the 'ButtonokButtonClicked' event to the 'Control Events' tab.

Comment: Added the contents of wxcrafter.h and wxcrafter.cpp to the main post. Will try to compile the minimal sample

Comment: Didn't compile the minimal sample, however I decided to check the output directory and the binary is there and it works fine... What doesn't work is the run option in the CodeLite 13 IDE, to run the binary directly from the IDE, but I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: @user12695000, you might post on the CodeLite forum/ML or ask directly in the C::L repository. Unfortunately, I'm not a C::L user, but it would be nice to know what went wrong.